# Understanding format specifiers in C

Tags: c

How does one explain:

```
int main()
{
unsigned char z=-1;
printf("%u %d",z,z);
}
```

gives 255 255?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about the specifiers, it's about the type - it's `unsigned`. As the range is `[0;255]` for `unsigned char` and `(unsigned xxx)-1` by standard, means - give the max value for unsigned xxx type.

---

Your code:

```
unsigned char z=-1;
```

has implicit conversion and it's the same as

```
unsigned char z= (unsigned char)-1;
```

So, `z == 255`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes since 255 is the value of z. [As you can find here](http://www.mekong.net/tech/printf.htm):

 `%u` will output the unsigned integer value, and

 `%d` will outputthe integer value

 The value 255 is represented the same both as unsigned int and integer, therefore you will see 255 twice.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared z as an unsigned char and then set it to -1.  So when you print it out the bit pattern set by -1 is display as an unsigned value 255.  Have a google for twos complement.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Because the binary bit pattern(Two's complement) of `-1` is `1111 1111`, and `z` is an `unsigned` type. And `unsigned` type of `1111 1111` is `255`.</s>

**Edit**

This is all about `implicit conversion` from a signed integer `-1` to an unsigned char, which is defined by the C language itself in `6.3.1.3`.

`6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers`

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool,
>   if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

Your case fits well into the *2nd* case, where `256(UCHAR_MAX+1) + (-1) = 255`, and it stays in the range of an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Conversion of `-1` to an unsigned type in C is not *because* of bit patterns, it's defined to convert by computing -1 modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`. With two's complement representation, this means the bit pattern doesn't change.

Comment: @John, Are you sure two's complement of `-1` is `1000 0001`? Take a look at here: [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking about the [Sign-and-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) method

Comment: @Eric Z:the %u specifier is ok,but %d should read 1111 1111 as -1.what's the problem over there?

Comment: @nikel, Just update my answer. It's not because of the bit pattern. It's all about implicit conversion in C.